# ASF+SDF environment : GLR Parser

Tags: parsing

Is it possible to write code in order to store intermediate values in user specified data structures in the ASF+SDF environment GLR Parser I would like compile the input source code in stages and have the output of each stage stored in a temporary dump file...like GCC does.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It was notoriously difficult to get intermediate results out of ASF+SDF specifications. Have a look at its successor called Rascal which is much more like a normal programming language.